# Problem with running a pre-trained ImageAI model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I'm running the code to learn how to teach AI/ML for object detection from this article:
https://medium.com/deepquestai/train-object-detection-ai-with-6-lines-of-code-6d087063f6ff
(very good one BTW ;-)

I downloaded pre-trained model and run it on Google Colab

It seems that I get an error of:
'''
 `--> 761             image_frame = image.copy()
    762             image_frame2 = image.copy()
    763             height, width, channels = image.shape`

```
'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy' 
on line 8: ----> 8 detections = 
detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image="holo3.jpg", 
output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")'
```

What could help here please because it should be a pre-trained, tested code?

I've searched through Stackoverflow and didn't find an answer.

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import CustomObjectDetection

detector = CustomObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath("hololens-ex-60--loss-2.76.h5") 
detector.setJsonPath("detection_config.json")
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image="holo3.jpg", 
output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")
for detection in detections:
print(detection["name"], " : ", detection["percentage_probability"], " : ", detection["box_points"])
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-31fc5f7df048> in <module>()
  6 detector.setJsonPath("detection_config.json")
  7 detector.loadModel()
----> 8 detections = 
detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image="holo3.jpg", 
output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")
  9 for detection in detections:
 10     print(detection["name"], " : ", 
detection["percentage_probability"], " : ", detection["box_points"])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageai/Detection/Custom/__init__.py in detectObjectsFromImage(self, input_image, output_image_path, input_type, output_type, extract_detected_objects, minimum_percentage_probability, nms_treshold, display_percentage_probability, display_object_name)
759 
760 
--> 761             image_frame = image.copy()
762             image_frame2 = image.copy()
763             height, width, channels = image.shape

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Comment: This might seem silly but have you checked that the image is actually in the path you're passing to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I found this similar error due to the train and validation folder annotation XML image path that does not exist inside the images folder. Check image names are the same as your annotation XML file paths.